# Code completion not working in Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I am upgrading from Delphi 7 to Delphi 2009.

In an existing app, the code completion does nothing at all.  If I start a new project, it works fine.

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 8):

Finally found the solution to this one, took awhile.

Added "WinTypes=Windows;WinProcs=Windows;DbiTypes=BDE;DbiProcs=BDE;DbiErrs=BDE" to:

Project Options -> Delphi Compiler -> Unit aliases

There is a whole big reason why, but to tired to explain it.