# Delphi IDE Editor doesn't show hints anymore

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

My Delphi 2009 has stopped today to show hints in the Editor-window. Nothing happens when I mouse-over any identifier. Tooltips for IDE-buttons are still shown.
I can also not CTRL-click anything anymore.
As far as I remember, I didn't change anything lately.
What could cause this?

Edit:
I found the setting, see my answer below.

Comment: Are you trying when debugging, or while coding?

Comment: It's while coding, for example right after starting the IDE, it was working fine until today.

Comment: Holgerwa: I assume it also happens if you create a brand new VCL project, as well (that is, I suppose the problem is not specific to any particular project)?

Comment: Andreas: I just tried. Yes, it also happens with a new project.

Comment: Did you recently install a Logitech webcam, or a Lexmark printer?  (No, this is not a joke)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the setting:
In Option / Editor Options / Source Options, there is a setting named "Use syntax highlight".

[image]

The help says: "Enables syntax highlighting. To set highlighting options, use the Color page".

This setting additionally enables / disables

- Hints on identifiers
- the ability to CTRL-click on identifiers
- the context menu entry "Find declaration"

I would have not expected this when reading the help text.

Thanks to all for your suggestions!

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried to restart the IDE?

If the problem persists, you might have disabled CodeInsight. To turn this on again, go to Tools/Options, select "Editor Options"/"Code Insight" and make sure that the options "Code Completion", "Tooltip Help Insight", "Auto Parenthesis", "Error Insight", "Block Completion", "Code Template Completion", "Code Parameters", "Auto Complete", "Tooltip Expression Evaluation", and "Tooltip Symbol Insight" are all checked.

[[image: Code completion options]
(High-Res)](https://privat.rejbrand.se/codecompletion.png)

Comment: I restarted IDE and Windows, my CodeInsight Options look exactly like yours, but it behaves as described in the question.

Comment: Downvoting without leaving a comment is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with code completion apparently not working and found that answer here [Code completion not working in Delphi 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169271/code-completion-not-working-in-delphi-2009)

You might find that this helps with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't you accidentally removed .NET framework? AFAIK some parts of Delphi IDE, like hints and refactorings, rely on .NET.